# What type of neural network can solve this problem

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

I have a dataset which is (6497 (number of samples), 13(number of features)). Each sample consists of 35-time steps each. I have to predict a target variable of each of these time steps, giving previous time steps as input for the next time step. for example, it should predict for 1st-time step (by taking only 12 features) and the output of 1st-time step has to be used as in input for the next step(along with features). Similarly, for 3rd time step, the first and second step out has to be used along with 12 features. Where can I start to design a network which solves this problem?

Comment: Just to clarify, you have 6497 matrices of size (35, 13) and the last column of each matrix is the dependent variable. Is this right?

Comment: Yes. Its the target variable.